Hood latch stuck
So the hood of my Hyundai Veracruz decided to fall shut when I stepped away from the car for a second. It fell on top of a plastic battery terminal cover I had set aside near the front. As it did so the hood got propped open on top of the plastic piece just enough to latch onto the hook of the latch assembly. Because the plastic piece is applying upward pressure on the hood, the latch is jammed tightly shut so the latch release doesn’t budge at all and I cannot push the hood down any further to give it some slack. WD40 and a screwdriver and hammer against the hook of the latch isnt working. Anything else I can do to get the hood open?

Ask your heaviest friend to place their ample fundament on the hood in the vicinity of the latch and bounce while you pull the hood release with a piece of string or wire. As soon as you feel the release disengage, tell the friend to stop bouncing.
Good luck.

Agreed, but would suggest the "heaviest friend" do so gently :o)

Tried applying extra pressure on the hood but no luck in breaking the plastic piece. Ultimately resorted to a near blind use of a reciprocating saw to break off just enough of the plastic to give some slack to slip the hook off.
Seems like I will have to replace the hood struts as my next task

Without knowing what you actually did with the reciprocating saw, this answer — if it's serious — is not very useful.

Extra weight on the hood did nothing to break the plastic piece. I had to tear through it with the saw to remove just enough to allow some slack so that the hook could be released from the hood

That makes sense, thanks. Please insert that information into the text of your answer (using the "edit" button below the text), as comments often don't last here on SE, and often disappear. Answers persist, so future readers can benefit from your experience and report. Thanks.

Very good. I withdrew my downvote, now changed to upvote.
